# Rewrite URL using .htaccess (adding query string)

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

http://www.naissancebebe.com/index.php?fc=module&module=prenoms&controller=search&gender=boy

I want to rewrite this using .htaccess to this way

http://www.naissancebebe.com/boy.php

so this query string  "index.php?fc=module&module=prenoms&controller=search&gender=boy" add in .htaccess file.

here is my code

```
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^boy.php /index.php?fc=module&module=prenoms&controller=search&gender=boy [L]
```

Comment: is that a typo ? `& gender=boy`? with a space?

Comment: oh no its just mistake there is no space

Comment: what is the problem with your code? whats not working?

Comment: Starkeen when i enter http://www.naissancebebe.com/boy.php it not redirect to /index.php?fc=module&module=prenoms&controller=search&gender=boy [L]

Comment: Do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: # Starkeen no i have not

Comment: Is there a " **#** " before "RewriteEngine on" line in your htaccess?

Comment: no i have not # mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^boy\.php$ /index.php?fc=module&module=prenoms&controller=search&gender=boy [QSA,NC,L]
```